# How can I put jQuery in a parent window if it doesn't have it?

Tags: jquery

I tried `parent.$ = $`, but I don't think this works because that's just a reference to the inner frame's jQuery, and any selectors will only search the inner frame.

If the parent window doesn't have jQuery already, how can I detect that and assign the paren't window's `$` variable to its own copy of jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

What if you do something like this. (Untested).

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    parent.document.jQuery || parent.document.write("<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js'>"+"<"+"/script>");
});
```

(Replace CDN with your own path if needed)